# Максимальное значение в словаре при помощи max и параметра key

Tags: python, словари

у меня к вам вопрос, мне необходимо при помощи функции MAX и параметра KEY вывести пару: ключ-значение, в которой значение максмимальное. Я сделал вот так:
подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли альтернативные варианты? Благодарю Вас.

```
 summer = {
'Июнь': [20, 22, 24, 28],
'Июль': [24, 25, 29, 32],
'Август': [25, 28, 31, 29]}

summer0 = {"Июнь": sum(summer["Июнь"]), "Июль": sum(summer["Июль"]), "Август": sum(summer["Август"])} 
print(f'{max(summer0, key=summer0.get)} : {max(summer0.values())}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Задача не совсем понятна (значение чего максимально - суммы значений в элементе словаря? а выводить нужно что в итоге?), но, допустим, можно так:

```
print(max(summer.items(), key=lambda t: sum(t[1])))
```

Вывод:

```
('Август', [25, 28, 31, 29])
```

Если нельзя использовать `lambda`, то есть вот такой вариант:

```
summer0 = [(sum(v),k) for k,v in summer.items()]
print(max(summer0))
```

Вывод:

```
(113, 'Август')
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас, да именно нужен вывод ключа и значение, НО вы знаете я не могу пока использовать Lambda по условию.

Comment: А что можно использовать? Самописную функцию можно в качестве ключа предоставлять? А `itemgetter`?

Comment: Добавил ещё вариант в котором даже и ключ не нужно указывать. Я просто не очень понимаю, что вы хотите писать в ключе, если `lambda` нельзя

Comment: Спасибо, здесь была задача при помощи max и key, поэтому lambda и itemgetter не могу использовать.

Comment: Но ведь вы должны что-то в `key` указать, вот я и спрашиваю - а что разрешено то там указывать? )

Comment: Извиняюсь, не понял вопроса, можно max или sum указать, но не получается у меня.